# colspan in an EJS template which may or may not display the option

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have a form like this, paraphrased

```
<% var inputType = json[i].inputType %>
<tr><td><%=json[i].question%></td></tr>
  ... //iterate over each question, then perform the following checks for each.
<% if(inputType == 'text') { %>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="text" class="full-width-textbox"></td>
  </tr>
<% } else if(inputType == 'rating') { %>
  <tr>
    <td>Hate it</td>
    <% for(var i=0; i<5; i++) { %>
      <td><input type="radio" value="<%=i%>" name="rating"></td>
    <% } %>
    <td>Love it</td>
  </tr>
<% } else { %>
  <% for(var j=0; j<json[i].answers.length; j++) { %>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="radio"></td>
    </tr>
  <% } %>
<% } %>
```

Now, the json I will be receiving in will be variable. I will not know what it is. Therefore, there is no assurance that I will be getting a "rating" question. I know that, usually, you can do a `colspan` but it doesn't seem to work in this circumstance.

How would I be able to render the ratings with the rest of the trs, such that it will have the following outcome?

```
1. who's your favorite super hero?
  [] thor
  [] green arrow
  [] my goldfish :|
2. what would you rate this question?
  Hate it [] [] [] [] [] Love it
```

... while still having the possibility of the json returning something like this and being able to handle for it?

```
1. do you like waffles?
  [] yeah we like waffles!
2. do you like pancakes?
  [] yeah we like pancakes!
3. do do do do do _____:
  [ text goes here        ]
```

Comment: Your question is not clear on exactly you are trying to achieve. Are you trying to make the radio button text appear to span the same number of columns as the rating? Your example json/html does not show text/labels next to each of the radio buttons. Describe the actual problem you are trying to solve and be more specific on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can make out of your question, you appear to want the questions and selections of each radio button to span the same amount of columns as the ratings.
You appear to not really want or need a table structure but rather just a list `ul` or `ol`.

Regardless of the overall structure, since radio buttons are inline elements they can just be in the same element (`<td>`).

```
<% } else if(inputType == 'rating') { %>
<tr>
  <td>Hate it
  <% for(var i=0; i<5; i++) { %>
    <input type="radio" value="<%=i%>" name="rating">
  <% } %>
  Love it</td>
</tr>
<% } else { %>
```

or

```
<% } else if(inputType == 'rating') { %>
<li>Hate it
  <% for(var i=0; i<5; i++) { %>
    <input type="radio" value="<%=i%>" name="rating">
  <% } %>
  Love it</li>
<% } else { %>
```